# HTML & CSS: manipulating font/text height?

Tags: html, css

I am using a custom font (Oswald) for the headings or titles within my page.  I believe that its' height is conflicting with the native fonts (Arial, san-serif etc.) and would like to know if there is a way to set both fonts evenly...?  If more text is placed in later on, the gap difference becomes substantial.

Please take a look at what I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/x6v7F/

I have a temporary background fade in and out to illustrate.

thank you.

Comment: Sorry Rob, I don't really understand what your problem is?

Comment: Are you saying the height of the Oswald 12px font does not match height of the 12px Arial font?

Comment: @Joshua M and Péter Varga...Basically each column should be the same height with the right amount of text...but because of the custom font in column two, it is shorter/longer than the others.  As Brook Julias mentioned, I believe something is wrong with the height of the 12px Oswald font as it doesn't seem to match the same height as the Arial 12px font and was wondering how to go about fixing this.

Comment: @Rob - I disagree that you're accepted answer is correct. It's a poor fix to a problem, which, unless I have misunderstood, I have provided a correct answer to?

Comment: playing w/ font size to line up the bottom of a section or div is a losing battle.

Comment: @JoshuaM I implemented the suggested code and at first it seemed to have worked, so I accepted that as a solution.  But looking over it again, I'd like to avoid setting a height for each column because if the user wanted to place more/less text in them, the text would write over/behind the buttons and would prefer to just make each text line, line up than fiddle with the buttons position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a `font-size` issue, the issue seemed to be with you specifying the `line-height`

If you see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x6v7F/1/) fiddle, you can see I've changed `h1` and `h2` to have these `line-heights`

```
h1 {
    font: 16px 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#000000;
    margin:14px 0;
    line-height: 100%; <----
}

h2 {
    font: 12px 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#BBBBBB;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    line-height: 100%; <----
    letter-spacing: .2px;    
}
```

If you check that Fiddle, it seems to have fixed your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort @Joshua M but with the columns layed out next to each other, it still displays columntwo's text a little higher or below the rest when I compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Rob has 4 sections that sit side by side (you may have to bump up width of jsfiddle window).  His prob is that he wants his sections to line up along the bottom, but is having issue because the varying text sizes between his body font and header fonts.

Many of the css grid frameworks try to address these type of issues: normalizing the heights of text and headers so that all lines fall on an imaginary grid of baselines.

To be honest, I would just give the sections a static height and leave some fuzzy space at the bottom for margin of error.

```
section { height: 370px; position:relative; }
section .button { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
```

**Edit**:

If you're looking for a dynamic section height, you'll have to leverage javascript magic.  JQuery:

```
  <style>
    section { position:relative; padding-bottom:50px; }
    section .button { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
  <style>

  <script>
    var max_height = 0;
    $('section').each(function() {
      max_height = Math.max(max_height, $(this).height());
    }).height(max_height);
  </script>
```

Comment: Spot on @ltiong_sh, but I'd like to avoid setting a height for the columns if possible, and would like to go down that path you suggested of normalizing the heights of the text and headers so that all lines fall on an imaginary grid of baselines.

Comment: it's a losing proposition, because at that point you would need to control the heights based on number of "rows".  If you decide to add 3 headers to a section..you would need to "recalculate" how many "rows" you would then be able to accommodate.